# Primefaces DataTable - reflow is not working on iOS

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

Primefaces DataTable reflow is not working on iOS.

Has anyone got this issue and found a workaround? Please assist.
However its the same issue on GitHub.

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1568#issuecomment-901261646

Comment: Doesn't this boil down to HTML + CSS? Or is JavaScript involved here? In case of HTML + CSS, include the rendered HTML and CSS and the respective tags to the question.

Comment: Hi there, have found strange problem. If we don't use Jsf template then DataTable reflow works in iOS. But with template reflow does not work but in android it works fine in both cases. I can provide the sample Jsf test project.